# how do i subscirbe/listen to events on the polygon blockchain using python

Tags: python, blockchain, cryptocurrency, web3py

I have recently developed an intrest in crypro currency and am currently working on a program that listens to emitted events from smart contracts.
it worked alright when tested on binance and ethereum blockchains but on polygon/matic i have encoutered a prblem - i get couple of errors which are either filter not found or that eth_newfilter does not exist depending on my rpc address is there any way to view events without showing all log entries (maybe web sockets)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.